# Insertar milesimas de segundo en INSERTS muy seguidos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, datetime, insert

Tengo un campo en mi tabla de MySQL que admite milésimas de segundo, porque lo que quiero lograr es que cuando se realicen INSERTS muy seguidos en la BD se guarden esas milésimas de segundo para saber que registro va antes que el otro, pero no hay manera, siempre se guardan los registros sin milésimas y en el orden que les da la gana...

Mirad como se guardan (todas las milésimas a 000):

```
2021-04-29 05:24:32.000 - Estado 3
2021-04-29 05:24:32.000 - Estado 1
2021-04-29 05:24:32.000 - Estado 2
```

Debería ser algo así como quiero que se guarden:

```
2021-04-29 05:24:32.067 - Estado 1
2021-04-29 05:24:32.123 - Estado 2
2021-04-29 05:24:32.364 - Estado 3
```

¿Alguien sabe como hacer los inserts para que se guarden las milésimas de segundo?
Gracias

---

Probé la solución de @Japv con el formato con ".v" y funcionó.

Sin embargo al final acabé usando la función `now(3)` de MySQL, metida directamente en la consulta desde PHP. También funciona perfecto y es más liviano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A partir de **MySQL 5.6** se permite trabajar con precisión de milisegundos en campos fechas. Para ello debemos declarar ese campo como **DateTime** y establecer una precisión al campo que va de **0** a **6**. Mientras mayor sea el valor de la precisión más exacta será la fecha. Para ello establecemos que esa columna será **DateTime(3)**, diciendo que su precisión será **3**, es decir se guardará la fecha, la hora y los milisegundos se darán con una exactitud de **3** **decimales**.

Otra forma de hacerlo es a través de este comando:

```
Alter Table MiTabla modifify campoFecha DateTime(3);
```

De esta forma reconfiguramos el tipo de dato para esa columna y entonces ya podemos insertar:

```
Insert into MiTabla(campoFecha) value (fechaActual);
```

Este **comando insert** es un ejemplo el tuyo será distinto.

Para añadir la fecha actual desde **PHP** puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$d = new DateTime('now');
echo $d->format('d/m/Y h:i:s.v');
```

En este código obtenemos la fecha actual y posteriormente la imprimimos usando el formato:

```
d/m/Y h:i:s.v
```

donde la **d** es el **día**, **m** el **mes**, **Y** el **año en cuatro cifras**, **h** la **hora**, **i** los **minutos**, **s** los **segundos**, **v** los **milisegundos**.

Para más información sobre fechas en **PHP** mira este enlace:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Te recomiendo que hagas una salva de los datos de la base de datos antes de modificar el campo, para evitar pérdida de datos.

Comment: Hola @Japv gracias, pero el campo ya lo tengo definido para que admita milisegundos. El problema es que si hago el insert con el valor NOW() (php) o CURDATE() (mysql) no me inserta los milisegundos.

Comment: @mdromed Se me olvido decirte que revisaras lo nuevo que puse,